# Passing function pointer to a function, which takes another function by reference

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am using this function of a library

```
template <
    typename funct, 
    >
double find_min (
    const funct& f, 
);
```

When I call **find_min(function_a)**, where **function_a** is a static function, it works. But when I try to encapsulate **find_min** in a function **run** and pass a function pointer to **find_min**, there is error, for example

```
class ABC {
    void run(double (*function_ptr)(double))
    {
        find_min((*function_ptr));
    }
}
```

Does this mean that I can only pass in a static function to **find_min**?

Comment: In `find_min((*function_ptr));` remove the `*`: `find_min(function_ptr);`

Comment: `find_min` of a function doesn't make sense, the first code block won't compile, and you haven't told anyone what your error is.

Comment: The only errors are the extra commas in the first snippet, and the missing semicolon at the end of the second. There's no reason why a function pointer can't be passed by reference to a function. Could you post some code that exhibits the error you're seeing, and tell us what that error is?

Comment: If you post a question about errors, you should always include the actual errors in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that sort of thing wouldn't work.  [See here.](http://ideone.com/m2UXa)  The only things I changed were:

- removed the invalid commas at the end of the template parameter list and function parameter list in the declaration of `find_min`.
- Made `ABC::run` public.